# Fullscreen absolute child positioning

Tags: html, css

I've been at this for a while, but I can't seem to figure out a proper way of doing this. Within my application I have a modal view inwhich there is a component that needs to take up the fullscreen. The problem I'm having is that the element is placed relative to their parent. While I need the positioning relative to the html body. Is there any way I can do this? I've made a simple fiddle showing the problem more clearly.

**HTML**

```
<div class="modal">
  <div class="fullscreen">
    test
  </div>
</div>

.modal {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.fullscreen {
  background: rgba(231, 29, 91, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x05h13u6/1/)

The only solution I've so far been able to find myself is the following;

```
.fullscreen {
  background: rgba(231, 29, 91, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  top: calc(-50vh + 50%);
  left: calc(-50vw + 50%);
}
```

But this isn't very pretty.

Comment: If the component in the modal needs to be full screen, why not just make the modal full screen and then position the component inside of it?

Comment: Absolute positioning always takes the closest positioned ancestor as reference point, and only if there is none all the way up to the root element, the reference point becomes the viewport. Perhaps switching to fixed would help? You'd need to remove the `transform` then, but there are other ways to center an absolute positioned element. https://jsfiddle.net/ecyLram0/1/

Comment: @AStombaugh the component that needs to go fullscreen is a carousel image slider, and the fullscreen mode enlarges the slider and places it on top of all the content so it the user can view an image fullscreen. Fullscreening the modal won't really do for me.

Comment: @CBroe this does seem to work nicely, only centering via `margin: auto` is stretching my modal to no longer wrap around the content.

Comment: @MartijnEbbens if your content is images, you might need to look into `object-fit` to keep them from stretching if you're using some fixed sizing like your example has. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Comment: @AStombaugh actually using flexbox instead for centering the modal seems do the trick together with `fixed` positioning! Cheers

Comment: Check out the dialog html element it might be just what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this issue by changing code to following.

```css
.modal-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.modal {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.fullscreen {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-container">
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="fullscreen">
      Test
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Have a read on to this mdn article it explains why your earlier solution didn't work.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Answer (score 0):

Please feel free to use the version of the modal provided here:

[JS Fiddle Link for Working Modal](https://jsfiddle.net/0tmnfkpL/)

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

I got that code from w3schools (it uses JavaScript in addition to CSS and HTML). All you would need to do is hit the button that's located in the top left corner of the results screen to show the modal.

However, if you really want to speed things up, you can look into using the bootstrap UI framework to build your frontend.